# How to get numbers out of this list of strings in python

Tags: python, string, list, numbers

I have a list of strings in python which I reading from a file:

```
    lines = ['4 11', '8 4', '10 5', '15 8', '4 3']
```

If I want to assign 4 and 11 to some variables. I do some thing like:

```
    a, b = lines[0][0], lines[0][2:]
```

Now I need to assign 10 and 5 to some variables, if I do some thing like:

```
    c, d = lines[2][0], lines[2][2:]
```

It gives:

```
   1
    5
```

So I am required to do:

```
    f, g = lines[0][0:2], lines[0][3]
```

to get the required result for that particular element of the list.

I have to automate this process for any input file. What am I doing wrong? Any help?

Comment: Use `split` instead of `slice` - Something like: `x, y = lines[0[.split(' ')`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
In [13]: lines = ['4 11', '8 4', '10 5', '15 8', '4 3']

In [14]: [[int(i) for i in line.split()] for line in lines]
Out[14]: [[4, 11], [8, 4], [10, 5], [15, 8], [4, 3]]
```

Now, you can iterate over the new list and assign whatever variables you'd like

**EDIT**:

If you want to read each pair of numbers only once, you could turn the list comprehension into a generator (just change the outer `[]` into `()`). This way, not all the results are stored in a list, and you get to access them one at a time:

```
([int(i) for i in line.split()] for line in lines)
```

Comment: Thanks!! It is working. My only concern is about memory issues, since I am already reading the whole file into the list and your [14] also creates another list which I am required to put it in to memory. Would it not be too much for my machine for larger files? Is there any work around?

Answer (score 2):

Instead of assuming which characters the numbers will be, you should use `split()`.

```
for num_pair in lines:
  a, b = lines.split()  # Splits based on whitespace
  # Do something with a and b
```

`split()` separates a string into a list of smaller strings, splitting based on whitespace (or, if you pass in a character as an argument, splits on that character).

Answer (score 0):

You can use map:

```
lines = ['4 11', '8 4', '10 5', '15 8', '4 3']
a,b = map(int,lines[0].split())
print a,b
4 11
a, b, c, d  = map(int,lines[0].split() + lines[2].split())
print a,b,c,d
4 11 10 5
```